# Formatting a cell in Excel - how to show a symbol in a specified position

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, libreoffice-calc

When formatting a cell in Excel (or LibreOffice), how can I have a certain symbol displayed in a specified position?

For instance, I want a cell formatted so that the sixth symbol is a hyphen, eg. "2121D-34".

Comment: You need to explain your problem in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can't do what you're you're asking. If your data was purely numerical, a Custom Cell Format of "#####-##" would work fine (displaying "1234567" as "12345-67"). However, as soon as you involve a non-numeric character (e.g. the "D" in your example), this no longer works. [One source I found](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/CustomFormats.htm) states that, when it comes to formatting cells in Excel, "there is not an awful lot more you can do with text".

I haven't used LibreOffice, but their [help wiki](http://help.libreoffice.org) shows that your results there will likely be similar, with plenty of numerical formats but few (if any) text formats available.

Answer (score 1):

From the Excel 'Format Cells' dialog:

> "Text format cells are treated as text even when a number is in the
>   cell.  The cell is displayed exactly as entered."

A work-around is to use a helper column that some text formulas.  Using your example,

```
=LEFT(E1,5)&"-"&RIGHT(E1,2)
```

will return your data formatted the way you want.  If your base data varies, then you'll have to get a little more sophisticated in your formula.